# How to resolve constant value referenced by an annotation attribute in an eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am writing an eclipse plugin that extracts values from an annotation and displays it in a view. One of the attributes is of string type and sometimes it is set with a constant.

For example:

```
@Annotation(attribute=Constant.SOME_CONSTANT)
```

Now to my question: When I extract the parts from the annotation, I want to resolve the actual value behind the constant. Is that possible using eclipse? And if yes, how can I do that?

What I have so far:

```
if (pair.getValueKind() == IMemberValuePair.K_QUALIFIED_NAME) {
    System.out.println("Constant");
    idValue = (String) pair.getValue();
}
```

That way I get according to the above example "Constant.SOME_CONSTANT" but I want "the constant value" instead.

Basically it seems that eclipse is capable somehow of doing this, because it can show the actual value of a used constant in a hovering window while you have the mouse cursor over it.

Comment: The `Constant` class is part of the users workspace I guess? I've asked a similar question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358624/load-a-class-from-the-users-workspace My solution was to load the `.class`-files from the bin-directory and extract the values. Not the best solution but it worked.

Comment: Yes, it is part of the workspace. I will have a look, but maybe there is a better solution.